# Executing python script with Runtime.getRuntime() is always return BLANK if the output is in Arabic

Tags: java, python, netbeans, encode

My main goal is to execute a `python` script and print the output in `Java Label`

For that, I create a file named `script.py` :

```
from transformers import AutoModelWithLMHead, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline


model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ar")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ar")
translation = pipeline("translation_en_to_ar", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
text = "I like study"
translated_text = translation(text, max_length=40)[0]['translation_text']

print(translated_text)
```

I execute the above script like this :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"python3", "C://scripts/script.py"});
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
   
String line;
String outputStr = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   outputStr = outputStr + line;
}
System.out.println("2) ==> " + outputStr);
reader.close();
```

The issue is when I execute this script, I get a blank output if the output is in **Arabic**, otherwise, everything works just fine with other languages.

When I execute the python code with **Jupyter Notebook**, I get this :

[image]

Note: I'm using `NetBeans` in Windows 10 to execute the python code.

Comment: Are you sure the font in your terminal can support the Arabic characters? Try it with `System.out.println<some Arabic string>);`

Comment: Yes, the output is being printed just fine

Comment: And how about outputting the Arabic text from Python to the console without Java?

Comment: fwiw I've just tried your Java on a script that just prints Arabic to the console with no problem.

Comment: Massive thanks for taking time to help me, I've fixed the issue, I just replace `print(translated_text)` with `sys.stdout.buffer.write(translated_text.encode("utf-8"))`, thank you again

Comment: Ha! Funnily enough, my script had that in it too ;)